# Should the “wp81” be eliminated/burninated in favor of "windows-phone-8.1"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

There are currently 6 questions tagged [wp81](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wp81), and 2,641 tagged [windows-phone-8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-8.1).  Is there any reason for the former to exist, or should it simply be merged into the latter?

Comment: Retag it (assuming thats what wp81 is). Somebody *really* lazy made up that acronym.

Comment: I can do that.  Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Once there are no posts with the tag, it will be deleted when the tag-cleanup script runs. Thats about it. Its not even worth a synonym to me. Make sure to fix any other problems you see with the posts!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The 6 posts have been re-tagged to [windows-phone-8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-8.1). May [wp81](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wp81) rest in peace.

Comment: Thanks.  I was going to wait for a bit in case anybody objected.

Comment: @dbc This one was obvious enough to me that I just went ahead and did it. That tag is *terrible*.